# Change switch back to previous value if condition is false

Tags: swift, woocommerce

I can't seem to change back to previous state when condition isn't evaluated to be "sucess".

```
func configureHideBloat(cell: SwitchTableViewCell) {
cell.onChange = { [weak self] newValue in
        let reason = "Log in with Face ID"
        context.evaluatePolicy(
            .deviceOwnerAuthentication,
            localizedReason: reason
        ) { success, error in
            if success {
                self?.hideBloat = newValue
            } else {
                cell.isOn = !newValue // Doesn't work as it says i shouldn't use isOn outside main thread..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make the switch go back to previous state if the else block is executed.

Comment: You should have a property inside data model of cell then using `tableView.reloadData()` or `tableView.reloadRows()` instead of setting cell's property.

Comment: @son i can't use tableView.reloadData() without using self, otherwise it throws an error "Reference to property 'tableView' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit", if i use self like this "self?.tableView.reloadData()" it throws this error: "UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only".